# dense_rank and sqlite - possible?

Tags: sqlite

My situation is that I have a `PostgresSQL` database that is pretty small (about 10 tables, biggest of which is a couple of thousand rows) and I want to use it from a single-user style application so having to install a whole server feels unnecessarily onerous.  So, I thought, well `SQLite` sounds like it will be just the ticket.

I ported over the schema, imported the data and then I got stuck on a view (actually, the only view it has).  My problem is that I am using the ever so handy `dense_rank` function.  I read this: [sqlite - Unsupported Sql Analytical Functions](http://www2.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=UnsupportedSqlAnalyticalFunctions) and can see that it is not available but it tipped me off that it may be in [SQLite::More](http://search.cpan.org/~kjetil/SQLite-More-0.10/lib/SQLite/More.pm) but it doesn't seem to be in there either.

So, does anyone know of any way I can get the `dense_rank` function to be available in a view inside a SQLite database?  Is there another library I can use perhaps?

Comment: What's the problem with running Postgres? Do you have very tight memory constraints? Is the installation a problem?

Comment: Yeah, installation mainly - seems like overkill to require a database server for something that is just a single user application.

Comment: Can't dense_rank be emulated by the code: For couple of thousands of rows it will not even be noticeable. I even think, the overall speed improvement by switching to sqlite will overshadow the additional burden of the rank-counting procedure.

Comment: Installation can be as easy as unzipping an archive. And the resource needs of an idle Postgres server are very low.

Comment: @a_horse But the resource and administration needs of SQLite are even lower. For simple work. (There's a point where using a server DB makes sense.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can emulate `DENSE_RANK` function with sub-queries:

Example:

```
SELECT Products.Product,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Products.Code DESC) AS Rank
FROM Products;
```

In SQLite:

```
SELECT Product,
(SELECT COUNT()+1 FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Code FROM Products AS t WHERE Code < Products.Code)
) AS Rank
FROM Products;
```

Comment: Great, thanks very much, that will do the trick nicely - I can live with slower performance since I have so few rows in my tables.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I've noticed that NULL-entries get `Rank=1` just like the lowest value that occurs in the data, just a heads-up if that might be an issue in your data.

Answer (score 3):

Update 2018: If you look at the sqlite version history dense_rank (among other window functions) is supported as of version 3.25.

https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html