# How to select records with order id in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I have a query that selects data in an alphabetical order. For example:

```
ID |TITLE
6  |A
35 |AA
3  |B
87 |BB
...
```

And I would like to select an `order id` of the record as well (`order id` it's not an actual column in the db). So the result should look like:

```
ID |ORDER ID |TITLE
6  |0        |A
35 |1        |AA
3  |2        |B
87 |3        |BB
...
```

How can I achieve something like this? I could check every returned record in a while loop and I would increase a counter on every iteration but that's not really what I want to do and I would rather leave this on database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind `RANK` function in other database engines.

In SQLite, you can achieve this like:

```
SELECT ID, (SELECT COUNT() FROM table AS t WHERE Title<table.Title), Title FROM table;
```

[dense_rank and sqlite - possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816626/dense-rank-and-sqlite-possible/18817860#18817860)

EDIT: Distinct order numbers:

```
SELECT ID, (SELECT COUNT() FROM table AS t WHERE Title<table.Title OR Title=table.Title AND ROWID<table.ROWID), Title FROM table;
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried it ,but it doesn't work properly. I've tested your query and it return absolutely wrong values + I've tried add "ORDER BY title" at the end of the query because I need it and it returned values as 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 30, 30, 30 etc...

Comment: That's because you have repeated names. It can be solved but you gave no directives how to handle this.

Comment: Sorting is made by "ORDER BY ..." ,so if I've got repeated/same values as (A, A, A, A, B, C, D) I need for them classic order as (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6). It doesn't matter which values are there... They are sorted and I need some index for them. Then I have to select for example item with id 234 which is for example third "A" and it will return me order id "2".

Comment: That is a new question! Create a new one!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE id = 3 ORDER BY title
```

This will return all fields in *yourtable* (id, order id, title) where the id column is 3

**Edited to add:**
Additional information from comment - include order_id in result set but not from table. To to this you can add a constant and alias the column like so:

```
SELECT id, '999' AS order_id, title FROM yourtable WHERE id = 3 ORDER BY title
```

This will return an order_id column with 999 as the value.

Comment: In my table I don't have any column called (order_id). I want to set it in SELECT query because it can be different in every select query. An it has to be from 0 to XXX.

Comment: Have a look at my edited answer, i'm still not 100% clear on what you're asking but that's my interpretation of the question(s)

Comment: Hi your example return order_id '999' ,but I need real order_id what means number 2 in example above. And if I have got for example one more value for "A" then letter "B" is going to be farther so it will have order_id with number 3. Basically I have to sort items in select query by alphabetical order and every item has to have some index. First item has 0, second item has 1, third item has 2 etc... I don't know how to explain it different. Thank you