# Sqlite - get numbered rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, rank

I am retrieving list of persons from a database and each person has some points. What I want to achieve is to get all person information along with person's points and rank. Points are calculated on the go, because they are not stored within the entity and the query looks something like that:

```
SELECT p.<some person attributes>, s.points, [here I need rank] as rank
FROM Persons p LEFT JOIN <subquery calculating points> s
ON p.id = s.personId
ORDER BY s.points DESC
```

In my select part I need to get a position in ranking of a person (what is basically order of returned rows, since I order it by points, right?)

Is there any sql/sqlite column or function to return that?

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what window functions are for. Specifically, `dense_rank` will also take care of pesky edge-cases where several users have the same number of points:

```
SELECT    p.<some person attributes> s.points,
          DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY points DESC) as "rank"
FROM      Persons p 
LEFT JOIN <subquery calculating points> s ON p.id = s.personId
ORDER BY  s.points DESC
```

Comment: It looks cool, but I end always end up getting extraneous input "(" after DENSE_RANK. I read here that it is unsupported in Sqlite

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816626/dense-rank-and-sqlite-possible

Comment: @MichałPowłoka It is [supported](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) with SQLite [3.25](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_25_0.html).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, SQLite is not very good at this.  You pretty much need to resort to a correlated subquery:

```
with s as (
      <subquery calculating points>
     )
select p.<some person attributes>, s.points,
       (select 1 + count(*)
        from s s2
        where s2.points > s.points
       ) as rank
from Persons p left join
     s
     on p.id = s.personId
order by s.points desc;
```

This specifically implements `rank() over (order by points desc)`.  Similar logic can be used for `dense_rank()` or `row_number()` if that is what you really need.